# Shortcut for create javascript function on webstorm / intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, webstorm

I've seen on [EggHead](http://www.egghead.io/) blog's some videos about coding AngularJS javascript apps. I realize that every time that he type `$scope.x = fun` the code completion open and he types some shortcut (which I don't know) that creates the following statement:

```
$scope.x = function () {
}
```

The normal code complete, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> <kbd>+</kbd> <kbd>space</kbd>, gives me:

```
$scope.x = function
```

Does anybody knows this shortcut or how to configure that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Most likely he has a custom [Live Template](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/live-templates.html) configured that expands `fun` with <kbd>Tab</kbd> into:

```
function () {
}
```

The template may look like this:

```
function () {
  $END$
}
```

Where `$END$` stands for the final cursor position after expanding.

Answer (score 4):

You should look into [Live Templates](http://www.jetbrains.com/idea/webhelp/live-templates.html) feature of IntelliJ. He could have created his own template for this.